# Looking for info on old ie5 code node.parentnode.level

Tags: javascript, dom, parent-node

Anybody have the slightest clue on what node.parentNode.level is supposed to do or what a replacement would be, I can't seem to find a reference to .level for a parentNode in the DOM specifications. It doesn't work for IE9 or Chrome. But works in IE5 mode. A couple of examples in code if(node.parentNode.level.length==1) in one section and another for node.parentNode.level.split("_"); node in both cases is a div.

Comment: Maybe if you provide more of the code we could figure out what the code is trying to do with level without needing the docs for it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've figured it out, the node was a div and the level was a custom attribute on the Div.  To get the value in Chrome I had to use
node.parentNode.getAttribute("level").split("_");